# Javascript break string on '.', based on preceding consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that I need to split into paragraphs. I can easily do this using `.split('. ')`, and appending a '.' char to each string - I then have an array of sentences. Running into issues though as the string may have names with an abbreviated middle name - John D. Doe, for example.

If it wasn't Javascript, I'd use a lookbehind, but it is so I can't.

How can I split the string into a set of sentences, delimited by two or more alphanumeric chars followed by a fullstop?

Thought this would work - `.split(/(?:\w{2}\.)\s/g)` - but it doesn't include the delimiter in the match, instead I lose the final char and fullstop from each split sentence.

Comment: What about a sentence like "I went to Mt. Rushmore"?

Comment: Yes. Same situation - hadn't allowed for two-letter truncations. Thank you

Comment: A slightly different approach would be to check instead if your word with a . starts with a capital letter.

Comment: @Dominic Green but that would still match abbreviations like "etc."

Comment: @DominicGreen: "John D. Doe" and "Mrs. Doubtfire was released on the 24th of Feb. 1994"

Comment: Hey by my comment I meant that, you could ignore any word that begins with a capital and ends with a . Like etc Mrs.

Comment: Don't forget also that a sentence can finish with an exclamation or a questionmark `[.?!]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a look behind by reversing your string and regex and use a lookahead.  Ref:http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};
var string = "John D. Doe and Mrs. DoubtFire went to Mt. Washington on 25 Feb. 1999. Another sentence.";
var newString = string.reverse().split(/\s(?=\.\w{4})/).map( function(a){ return a.reverse(); } ).reverse();
```

Edit: You'll need another .reverse() on the array too or your sentences will be in the wrong order

Comment: It would be much simpler to use `match` instead of `split`, then there's no need for lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, but this works for the "Mt. Rushmore" & "Mrs. Doubtfire" problem.

Comment: But it creates a new problem. Try a string like "I'm not sure what you're getting at. This creates another problem."

Comment: You good sir, are the man. Works perfectly and makes really good sense (should really avoid beer + dev). Thanks heaps.

Comment: And there's still no reason to use `split`, reverse the string, break encapsulation by modifying `String.prototype`, etc. You could "solve" that problem with `match` just as easily.

Comment: Can you please explain what possible benefit all this code might have over simply doing `string.match(/.*?\w{4,}\./g)`?

Comment: @Synthetx, sorry, didn't mean to be rude, I just have to deal with a lot of unnecessarily complex code and it tends to rub me the wrong way.

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit: I know that feel :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I split the string into a set of sentences, delimited by two or more alphanumeric chars followed by a fullstop?

If these are the only constraints, you can `match` a pattern like this:

```
/.*?\w{2,}\./g
```

However, this wouldn't solve the "Mt. Rushmore" and "Mrs. Doubtfire" problems mentioned in the comments.

Using `match` instead of `split` is the key here, so you don't need lookbehinds.

http://jsfiddle.net/6tnQ3/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `\n` instead of `.` at the end of the paragraph. In this way you can split them easily without being worried about conflicts between characters that could be used in text.

Comment: Not if I follow what you're saying - the original text is a single string, so \n doesn't exist.

Comment: You can identify 'end.' pattern with regex test, where end is a word with more than one character. Through this you will find end of each sentence.